# how to give a standart or a user value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

How to give my `input` field a `0` when the user don't types in a value? 
Should i do it with a

```
if  {
} 
else {
}
```

Comment: *Just* an `if{}else{}` isn't gonna cut it ;-)  Use an EventListener, and then check the value

Comment: please better explain **exactly** what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it in javascript then submit the form via javascript. We are now setting the value of the number input programmatically then after this we are submitting it programmatically.

```js
function setZero() {
  const input = document.getElementById('number');
  
  if(!parseInt(input.value)){
      input.value = 0;
  }

   console.log(input.value);
    
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
<input id="number" type="text" value="1">
<button type="button" onclick="setZero()">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet to check and set 0 for a textbox.

```
<script>

function checkVal() {
  var txtVal=document.getElementById('txtBx').value;
  if(txtVal=="")
  {
      document.getElementById('txtBx').value=0;
  }

}

</script>

<input id="txtBx" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="checkVal()">Button</button>
</form>
```